# How to replace URL " " by "-" or "_"?

Tags: url, url-rewriting, yii

In YII
If there is blank space in title which is being used for url, then by default blank spaces are replaced by "+" sign. Something like this:

> www.domain.com/event/view/id/**Dj+Robag+Ruhme**

What I want to do is, I want to replace "+" sign by "-" (dash sign) or by "_" (underscore). Something like this:

> www.domain.com/event/view/id/**Dj-Robag-Ruhme**

or

> www.domain.com/event/view/id/**Dj_Robag_Ruhme**

Right now my urlManager is:

```
'urlManager'=>array(
    'urlFormat'=>'path',
    'showScriptName'=>false,
    'caseSensitive'=>false,
    'rules'=>array(
        //'<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
        //'<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
        //'<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
        ),
),
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, nothing strange since Yii use [`urlencode`](http://php.net/manual/function.urlencode.php) to encode url parameters.

**First approach**

You could handle this in your model, e.g. :

```
public function getUrl()
{
  return Yii::app()->createUrl('/model/view', array(
    'id'=>str_replace(' ', '-', $this->id),
  ));
}
```

Don't forget to :

- replace `model` with the name of your model,
- use this method to get your model url,
- modify your view action in your controller :

  ```
  public actionView($id)
  {
      $id = str_replace('-', ' ', $id);
      // .....
  }
  ```

**Second approach**

You could use your own [`CUrlRule`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CUrlRule) class :

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.url#using-custom-url-rule-classes

Comment: I am new to YII. Where should I put this method, I have tried in my Event model, but it didn't change anything?

Comment: Read carefully my answer, you have to use `getUrl` to build your events links

Comment: Its not working. I have used getUrl method in my event model, but still I am getting "+".

Comment: Did you modify your views to use `getUrl` instead of default url ? If you don't want to modify your views you should consider using my second approach.

Comment: When I use this function, it is successfully change the url but I get an `Error 404
The requested page does not exist.`