# How to replace dash(-) instead of space in url?

Tags: php, .htaccess, yii2

I am using Yii2, I am trying to change Url **spaces** to **dash(-)**.

The browser I'm using puts **plus(+)** instead of **spaces** in Url, in default;

For example this sentence:

**"how to replace dash instead of space"**

changes to:

**/mysite.com/how+to+replace+dash+instead+of+space**

But I want put **dash(-)** instead of **plus(+)** like blow Url:

**/mysite.com/how-to-replace-dash-instead-of-space**

Comment: Be sure of this because - (dash)  is used in url  routing convention by Yii2 and match with the upper case in action name ..

Comment: @scaisEdge how can I check it in yii2?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Yii2 Url Html format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26360249/yii2-url-html-format)

Comment: I have posted an answer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to replace URL " " by "-" or "\_"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16186620/how-to-replace-url-by-or)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following rule in htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine on

#1If uri has spaces, convert them to hyphens and set an  env "hasspaces"
RewriteRule (.*)\s(.*) $1-$2 [N,E=hasspaces:yes]
#2if the env "hasspaces" is set, we will redirect spaces to hyphens 
RewriteCond %{ENV:hasspaces} yes
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /$1 [L,R]
```

This will convert all spaces in uri to hyphens and redirect the url

- example.com/hello word

to

- example.com/hello-word

Comment: RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php

Comment: there are that code in my htaccess, how can i add your code to that?

Comment: @Farshid you have to put this bellow the rule i posted othewise it will conflict with that.

Answer (score 0):

Before doing this Be sure  because `-` (dash) is used in url routing convention by Yii2 and match with the upper case in action name

> **Controller Class Naming**
>
> Controller class names can be derived from
> controller IDs according to the following procedure:
>
> Turn the first letter in each word separated by hyphens into upper
> case. Note that if the controller ID contains slashes, this rule only
> applies to the part after the last slash in the ID. Remove hyphens and
> replace any forward slashes with backward slashes. Append the suffix
> Controller. Prepend the controller namespace. The following are some
> examples, assuming the controller namespace takes the default value
> app\controllers:
>
> article becomes app\controllers\ArticleController; post-comment
> becomes app\controllers\PostCommentController; admin/post-comment
> becomes app\controllers\admin\PostCommentController;
> adminPanels/post-comment becomes
> app\controllers\adminPanels\PostCommentController. Controller classes
> must be autoloadable. For this reason, in the above examples, the
> article controller class should be saved in the file whose alias is
> @app/controllers/ArticleController.php; while the admin/post-comment
> controller should be in
> @app/controllers/admin/PostCommentController.php.

for a complete guide see this http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-controllers.html
and http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-controllers.html